# Laravel 5.1 - Eloquent Relationships

Tags: eloquent, one-to-many, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel. I was looking at the Eloquent relationships. I followed the documentation and defined my one to many relationship as:

```
// in the test model
 public function questions()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Question', 'test_name_id', 'test_id');
   }
// in the question model
public function test()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Test', 'test_name_id', 'test_id');
   }
```

Note that i have not followed the convention for naming the id's. So if I do this in the Tinker:

```
$test = App\Test::first();
$question = $test->questions;
```

It works fine. But if want the record any other than first like doing:

```
$test = App\Test::where(['test_id'=>'2'])->get();
$question = $test->questions;
```

It gives me this error:

```
PHP error:  Trying to get property of non-object on line 1
```

Can any one please explain me what I am doing wrong here and how does this work properly?

Comment: Try ->first() instead of get(). get() returns array. Or use protected $primaryKey = 'test_id'; in test model and then find(id)

Comment: can you describe both table schemas please?

Comment: @TimvanUum, that helped alot. :)

Comment: @TimvanUum please include that in an answer to be accepted and close the question.

Comment: @SalmanGhauri Done. Glad it helped you :)

Comment: @TimvanUum Thanks for helping the OP and the community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `->first()` instead of `get()`. `get()` returns array. Or use `protected $primaryKey = 'test_id';` in test model and then `->find($id)`